# Replace URLs in Typo3 DB

Tags: mysql, database, typo3

So I have a Site created with Typo3. I also have a domain which is linked to the folder of the Typo3 Installation. www.example.org

I created a Subdomain and linked it to the same folder and used the Main Domain for something else.

But now everything on the Subdomain still has the URL Structure of the main site so when I open up sub.example.org all the Links and Images still have the URL from www.example.org/...

I exported the Database and replaced every URL with notepad++ and imported it again. But that didnt change anything. What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two (three with realurl) places where you need to look if changing the domain of a TYPO3 site, if everything is done by the book and noone hardcoded the domain all over the place or something.

Usually you do not need to work in the database directly.

After doing the changes, make sure to clear the caches (install tool in 6.2+, "all caches" in earlier versions).

**First**:
There are two TypoScript settings that influence the generated URL: [`config.baseURL`](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Config/Index.html#setup-config-baseurl) and [`config.absRefPrefix`](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Config/Index.html#setup-config-absrefprefix).

The recommended way to use those is to not set `config.baseURL` (would result in a `<base>` tag in the HTML `<head>`), and set `config.absRefPrefix` to the subpath where TYPO3 is, relative to the document root. If TYPO3 lies directly in the document root, set it to `/`.

**Second**:
In the database, there are "Domain Records". They are usually located on the root page of a site. Change those to the new domain.

**Third** (with realurl only):
Check the realurl configuration file, usually located in `typo3conf/realurl_conf.php`. Depending on your setup, the old domain name is used there and needs to be changed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I open up the typo3 Backend and navigate to "Template" and click on "Typoscript-Templates" and open up the config it shows something like: config {... and later the baseURL and absRefPrefix and those two are set to the new subdomain. I also looked up the sql files and there are no absolute paths there for images and so on so replacing the database with the new url wont work. I dont have a realurl_conf.php in the folder typo3conf. I have typo3 ver. 4.5.6 installed

Comment: The `realurl_conf.php` file does not need to have that name, that's just the default. It name can be set in the settings of the extension `realurl`, which can be seen and modified in the extension manager. But I suspect either one of two things here: 1) a domain record is to blame. Go to the "List" module and open the root page, the record is probably there. 2) The TypoScript settings listed above are overwritten later in the template, or on subpages. Check their final values using the TypoScript Object Browser, it can be found in the Template module as well.

Comment: Ok there is no extension realurl. What do you mean with open the root page at the list module? I checked every file of the Web>List Module but didnt find anything with a url in it, or what do I need to search for? Same with the Web>Template, Object Browser.

Comment: Ok I just saved the typoscript baseURL and absRefPrefix again and now it seems to work...was a cache problem after all I guess. (I dont know how to clear the cache in typo3, using it for the first time) Thank you really much for the help!

Comment: You can clear the cache with the lightning-icon in the upper right corner, besides the logout button. In 6.2+ you can also clear the caches in the install tool, which is a bit more radical, but needs admin rights.